# Django, Wagtail admin: handle many to many with `through`

Tags: django, wagtail

I have 2 models with a **through** table such as:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    bs = models.ManyToManyField(to='app.B', through='app.AB', blank=True)

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('fields'),    # what should go here?
    ]

class AB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(to='app.A')
    b = models.ForeignKey(to='app.B')
    position = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['a', 'b']
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to save:

> Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.

That error makes sense to me. I should save AB instances instead. I'm just unsure what's the best way to achieve that in Wagtail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is an InlinePanel: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#images

```
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

# the parent object must inherit from ClusterableModel to allow parental keys;
# this happens automatically for Page models
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

class A(ClusterableModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        InlinePanel('ab_objects'),
    ]

class AB(Orderable):
    a = ParentalKey('app.A', related_name='ab_objects')
    b = models.ForeignKey('app.B')
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('b'),
    ]
```

Comment: I had tried the `InlinePanel` which resulted in a key exception. What I was missing was the use of `ParentalKey` & `ClusterableModel`.

Comment: I think ParentalKey above should be without "models."

Comment: Is there a way to change `InlinePanel`'s widget?

Comment: @Ramesh-X No - an InlinePanel doesn't have a corresponding widget, as it generates a formset instead.