# Edit django 'through' model inline in wagtail admin?

Tags: django, wagtail

[Edited with better code sample]

As per the title I am trying to allow for inline editing for a very simple shop page in Wagtail (will probably make it into a simple package):

With the following models:

```
class Product(ClusterableModel):
    page = ParentalKey(MiniShopPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shop_products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2500)
    downloadable = models.BooleanField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    # define the content_panels
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('description'),
        FieldPanel('downloadable'), 
        FieldPanel('price'), 
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
    ]

class Order(TimeStampedModel, ClusterableModel):
    '''
    Example of use outside of the admin:
    p = Product.objects.first()
    order = Order.objects.create(client_email='someone@hotmail.com', gift_amount=0)
    quantities = ProductInOrderCount(product=p, order=order, quantity=2)
    quantities.save()

    for itm in order.productinordercount_set.all():                          
        print(itm.quantity)
    '''
    is_fulfilled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_paid_for = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    client_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    gift_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # products = M2MTHROUGH
    # the through model stores the quantity
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductInOrderCount')

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('is_fulfilled'),
        FieldPanel('is_paid_for'),
        FieldPanel('client_email'),
        FieldPanel('gift_amount'),
        InlinePanel('products'),
    ]

    class OrderModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
        model = Order
        menu_label = 'Orders'
        ...

    modeladmin_register(OrderModelAdmin)

class ProductInOrderCount(Orderable):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The tricky thing is that I get the error `Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.` Or I simply don't get an inline panel, but rather a select.

I am assuming this is the case because the create and add methods do not work on through models, is that the case?

If so could you suggest a way I can rewrite the app so as to allow me to create orders with products in the admin and in my code?

Comment: I think you need to share a bit more of your code for this question to be meaningful - there aren't any `ManyToManyField`s in the code you've given.

Comment: You're right. I adapted the M2Mfields to match the suggestion you gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209851/django-wagtail-admin-handle-many-to-many-with-through but maybe that does not really apply here?

Comment: OK, I'm even more confused now. Are you saying that the code snippet above is the result of changing the model definition as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209851/django-wagtail-admin-handle-many-to-many-with-through to avoid a `ManyToManyField`, but you're still getting a `ManyToManyField` error? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think your comment and my edit just crossed each other @gasman Apologies. You are right I tried two approaches, I've rewritten the question to reflect a single question and not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InlinePanel` only works with one-to-many `ParentalKey` relations, not a `ManyToManyField`. That shouldn't be a problem, because `ParentalKey` is a good fit for this case:

- A `ManyToManyField` with a `through` model is really just two one-to-many relations back to back;
- `ParentalKey` is designed for relations that are closely tied to the parent model, in the sense that they're always edited, validated and saved as a single unit. This is true for the relation between `ProductInOrderCount` and `Order` (a `ProductInOrderCount` record is conceptually part of an `Order`), but not the relation between `ProductInOrderCount` and `Product` (a `ProductInOrderCount` is not part of a `Product`).

This would give you a model definition like:

```
class ProductInOrderCount(Orderable):
    order = ParentalKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ordered_products')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Your `Order` model can then have an `InlinePanel('ordered_products')`, and the `products` field can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to see I had to use `panels` now. Great answer. Just a quick follow up: how come the modeladmin, for instance, when using list_display, shows the ordered_products as `core.ProductInOrderCount.None`?